# Unknown sample rate/Line Unavailable - Java

Tags: java, centos7, javasound, sample-rate, audioformat

I am working on a Java based Application that requires to record sound from Mic. Following is my code:

```
audioFormat = new AudioFormat(8000, 16, 1, true, false);
        targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);

        try {
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat, 320);
            targetDataLine.start();

        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SoundManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Here I am getting exception on line "targetDataLine.open(audioFormat, 320);"

> javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format
>   PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not
>   supported.

I have changed my PC's hardware and OS to CentOS7, the same code worked perfectly on previous hardware and OS CentOS 6.7.

I have checked the formats that my current PC Supports, which are as follows:

```
> Supported SourceDataLines of default mixer (PCH [default]):
> 
> interface SourceDataLine supporting 48 audio formats, and buffers of
> at least 32 bytes   max buffer size:  -1   min buffer size:   32  
> Supported Audio formats: 
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, 3 channels, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, 3 channels, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, 4 channels, 8 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, 4 channels, 8 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
>     PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
>     PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, 3 channels, 3 bytes/frame, 
>     PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, 3 channels, 3 bytes/frame, 
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, 4 channels, 4 bytes/frame, 
>     PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, 4 channels, 4 bytes/frame, 
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 32 bit, mono, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 32 bit, mono, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 32 bit, stereo, 8 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 32 bit, stereo, 8 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 32 bit, 3 channels, 12 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 32 bit, 3 channels, 12 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 32 bit, 4 channels, 16 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 32 bit, 4 channels, 16 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 8 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 8 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 3 channels, 12 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 3 channels, 12 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 4 channels, 16 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 4 channels, 16 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 3 channels, 9 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 3 channels, 9 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 4 channels, 12 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 4 channels, 12 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 20 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 20 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 20 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 20 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 20 bit, 3 channels, 9 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 20 bit, 3 channels, 9 bytes/frame, big-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 20 bit, 4 channels, 12 bytes/frame, little-endian
>     PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 20 bit, 4 channels, 12 bytes/frame, big-endian
```

I will be grateful if I get some sort of help in this regards.

Comment: Have you tried `targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);` instead of `targetDataLine.open(audioFormat, 320);`?

Comment: @hendrik I have tried that, but the exception is still the same.